# Erro com o decorator do tsyring

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm, tsyringe

Estou trabalhando com o tsyringe, ele funciona corretamente mas ao fazer a injeção de dependencia pelo decorator inject, o codigo apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Não é possível resolver a assinatura do decorador de parâmetro quando ele é chamado como uma expressão.
  O argumento do tipo 'undefined' não é atribuível ao parâmetro do tipo 'string | symbol'.ts(1239)" `
```

O curioso é que o codigo funciona normalmente,a injeção de dependencia funciona mesmo com o vs-code apontando o erro.

**Container.ts**

```
import { container, Lifecycle } from 'tsyringe';

container.registerSingleton<IOrderRepository>(
  'OrderRepository',
  OrderRepository
);
```

**useCase.ts**

```
@injectable()
class AlterOrderUseCase {
  constructor(
    @inject('OrderRepository') private repository: IOrderRepository
  ) {}
}
```

É nessa parte que ocorre o erro **@inject('OrderRepository')** Como posso resolver esse erro ?

Versão do Tsyring: ^4.7.0
Versão do Typescript: ^4.9.4

Answer (score 0):

Descobri como resolver, na paleta de comandos do VS Code procure por *Selecionar a versão do typescript* Vai aparecer a lista de versões do Typescript disponivel do seu computador, escolha a que versão do workspace.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, o erro vai sumir.